# Lots Repositories In Project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, ninject

I'm using ninject controller factory to bind some repositories to controllers via interfaces...

```
public class NinjectControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory 
{
    private IKernel ninjectKernel;

    public NinjectControllerFactory() 
    {
        ninjectKernel = new StandardKernel();
        AddBindings();
    }

    protected override IController GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType) {
        return controllerType == null ? null : (IController)ninjectKernel.Get(controllerType);
    }

    private void AddBindings() 
    {
        ninjectKernel.Bind<ISystemDefinition<CentreModel>>().To<CentreRepository>();
        ninjectKernel.Bind<ISystemDefinition<ResidentStatusModel>>().To<ResidentStatusRepository>();
    // here will be the list of lots of repositories with different models
    }

}
```

Imagine that i need to write about hundred forms with different data, so i need to have at least different models...(maybe with same "IReposotory"), but i still need to add model into "AddBindings()" method... Is it ok? (I'm not sure)...
What is the best practice to store repositories with different models into controllers?

Model is for example:

```
public class CentreModel : BaseModel {
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "*")]
    [Display(Name = "Name:")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Order:")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "*")]
    public int SortOrder { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Is active:")]
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "*")]
    [Display(Name = "Associated centre:")]
    public int AssociatedCentreId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<CentreListModel> OldCentres { get; set; }
}
```

Interface example:

```
public interface ISystemDefinition<T> where T : class,new()
{
    IEnumerable<T> GetList(bool? isActive = null);
    IEnumerable<T> GetList(bool? isActive = null, int? OwnerID = null);
    T Fetch(int? ID);
    void Save(T item);
    void Remove(T item);
    void Order(List<T> items);
}
```

And Repository example:

```
public class CentreRepository : BaseRepository, ISystemDefinition<CentreModel> {
    public IEnumerable<CentreModel> GetList(bool? isActive) {
        return (from c in entities.Centres
                where c.IsActive == isActive || isActive == null
                orderby c.SortOrder
                select new CentreModel {
                    ID = c.ID,
                    Name = c.Name,
                    IsActive = c.IsActive,
                    SortOrder = c.SortOrder,
                    AssociatedCentreId = c.AssociatedCentreID
                });
    }

    public CentreModel Fetch(int? ID) {
        return (from c in entities.Centres
                where c.ID == ID
                orderby c.SortOrder
                select new CentreModel {
                    ID = c.ID,
                    Name = c.Name,
                    IsActive = c.IsActive,
                    SortOrder = c.SortOrder,
                    AssociatedCentreId = c.AssociatedCentreID
                }).FirstOrDefault();
    }

    public void Save(CentreModel model) {
        Centre centre = model.IsNew ? new Centre() : entities.Centres.Where(c => c.ID == model.ID).SingleOrDefault();

        centre.Name = model.Name;
        centre.SortOrder = model.SortOrder;
        centre.IsActive = model.IsActive;
        centre.AssociatedCentreID = model.AssociatedCentreId;

        if (model.IsNew) entities.Centres.Add(centre);

        Save();
    }

    public void Remove(CentreModel model) {
        Centre centre = model.IsNew ? new Centre() : entities.Centres.Where(c => c.ID == model.ID).SingleOrDefault();
        entities.Centres.Remove(centre);

        Save();
    }

    public void Order(List<CentreModel> items) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    public IEnumerable<CentreModel> GetList(bool? isActive = null, int? OwnerID = null) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you have different repository for each model? Can you post a sample of model and repository class?

Comment: public interface ISystemDefinition<T> where T : class,new()
    {
        IEnumerable<T> GetList(bool? isActive = null);
        IEnumerable<T> GetList(bool? isActive = null, int? OwnerID = null);
        T Fetch(int? ID);
        void Save(T item);
        void Remove(T item);
        void Order(List<T> items);
    }

Comment: Simple model for example:    public class CentreModel : BaseModel {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "*")]
        [Display(Name = "Name:")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Order:")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "*")]
        public int SortOrder { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Is active:")]
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "*")]
        [Display(Name = "Associated centre:")]
        public int AssociatedCentreId { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<CentreListModel> OldCentres { get; set; }
    }

Comment: And Repository just implements ISystemDefinition interface with CentreModel

Answer (score 2):

Rather than creating a repository for each model you might be better of creating a single concrete generic repository.

EDIT

For instance if you had the following interface:

```
public interface IRepository<TEntity> : IDisposable where TEntity : class 
{
    IQueryable<TEntity> GetAll();
    IQueryable<TEntity> GetAllIncluding(params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] includeProperties);
    TEntity Find(params object[] keys);
    void Add(TEntity entity, bool save = true);
    void Edit(TEntity entity, bool save = true);
    void Delete(bool save = true, params object[] keys);
    void Save();
}
```

You could have a single concrete implementation(example uses EF):

```
public class Repository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    private readonly DbContext _context;

    public Repository(DbContext context)
    {
        if (context == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("context");
        _context = context;
    }

   public IQueryable<TEntity> GetAll()
   {
        return _context.Set<TEntity>();
   }

   public IQueryable<TEntity> GetAllIncluding(params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] includeProperties)
   {
        IQueryable<TEntity> queryable = GetAll();
        return includeProperties.Aggregate(queryable, (current, includeProperty) => current.Include(includeProperty));
   }
public TEntity Find(params object[] keys)
   {
        return _context.Set<TEntity>().Find(keys);
   }
... etc. 
}
```

Then you can bind the open generic interface to the open generic repository as below:

```
Bind(typeof(IRepository<,>)).To(typeof(Repository<,>));
```

Also for my example you would need to bind the context to be injected into the repository constructor:

```
Bind<DbContext>().To<MyDbContext>();
```

This should then correctly instantiate a repository for any kind of model without having to have an explicit binding for each one.

So with the below controller constructor:

```
protected readonly IRepository<SomeEntity> _repository;

protected BaseController(IRepository<SomeEntity> _repository)
{
    _repository = repository; 
}
```

Ninject would inject a `Repository<SomeEntity>`.

Comment: Thanks for this, but could you please explain in more details?